# Is there any Rubygems or Rails method that can display how long it took to generate the webpage, and time in controller vs in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Alternatively, I can write a bunch of `Time.now` and print out the subtractions but is there a standard way it can be done by gems or by Rails' standard and conventional method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at Railscast [98](http://railscasts.com/episodes/98-request-profiling) and [161](http://railscasts.com/episodes/161-three-profiling-tools).

I've used [NewRelic's](http://www.newrelic.com/) hosted plan and it's definitely a great tool if the basic plan meets your needs or you can afford a paid plan. I haven't played around with the [developer mode](http://support.newrelic.com/faqs/docs/developer-mode) yet but it looks pretty good, especially for being free. [Rack::Bug](http://github.com/brynary/rack-bug) look nice too I might just have to take it for a spin.

Comment: +1. I'm also using NewRelic RPM for such tasks, developer mode works just fine. However, free version doesn't show you the time in controller vs the view, only the time in Ruby vs Database vs External services. Still, it's enough to find performance bottlenecks in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a statment on the top/end of your application.html.erb?

```
# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_filter :set_start_timer

def set_start_timer
    @start_time = Time.now
end
end

# application.html.haml
=@start_time # this is the overall processing time
=Time.now # this is the start view render time
=yield
=Time.now # this is the view render time after processing content
```

Comment: isn't that what i said in the original post?

Comment: If you insert it into your application.html.erb you only have to write 2 single statements at all.

Comment: and then modify `ApplicationController` to also do a `@time_start = Time.now`?